# Can't access global associate array using indirect expansion?

Tags: bash, global-variables, variable-expansion

I have the following setup:

```
#! /bin/bash

init_globals() {
    declare -gA global_arr1=( ["key"]="val" )
}
init_globals

echo "${global_arr1["key"]}" # WORKS! print val

local_arr1=( ["key"]="local val" )
i=1
temp=local_arr$i
current_arr=${!temp}
echo ${current_arr["key"]} # WORKS! print local val

temp=global_arr$i
current_arr=${!temp}
echo ${current_arr["key"]} # DOESN'T WORK! expect val but print nothing...
```

I'm trying to access globally defined associative array, based on the variable i. So I use indirect expansion to assign `current_arr` to what I want. It works perfectly for an associative array defined locally. But it doesn't work with global array. Why so?

Comment: This is the point where you are probably better off switching to a language with proper data structure support. Regular arrays have a purpose in shells (passing lists of whitespace-containing values as distinct arguments) aside from trying to build data structures. Associative arrays, on the other hand, seem like a very limited substitute for real, first-class container data structures.

Comment: @chepner Haha, I totally agree. My company and co-workers don't. They love bash too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare `local_arr1` as an associative array. It springs into existence with

```
local_arr1=( [key]="local val" )
```

so bash creates a normal array for you, with `key` understood as a variable whose value is the index in the array (zero in this case, as there's no `$key`). You can test it with `set -eu` or `key=1`.

Note that the correct way to use indirection on arrays is to include the index in the string:

```
arr1[2]=x
i=1
j=2
tmp=arr$i[$j]
echo ${!tmp}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it now. +1 for the example

Answer (score 1):

It is because:

```
local_arr1=( ["key"]="local val" )
```

is not really an associative array. You can check by:

```
declare -p local_arr1
```

which prints:

```
declare -a local_arr1='([0]="local val")'
```

If you use it right:

```
declare -A local_arr1=( ["key"]="local val" )
```

then behavior will be same for both arrays.